# Intuition behind incrementing the iteration variable?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am solving a question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-colors/description/):

> Given an array with n objects colored red, white or blue, sort them in-place so that objects of the same color are adjacent, with the colors in the order red, white and blue.  Here, they use the integers 0, 1, and 2 to represent the color red, white, and blue respectively.  [The trivial counting sort cannot be used].
>
> For the input: [2,0,2,1,1,0]; the output expected is: [0,0,1,1,2,2].

One of the [highly upvoted solutions](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-colors/discuss/26472/Share-my-at-most-two-pass-constant-space-10-line-solution/25489) goes like this:

```
   public void sortColors(vector<int>& A) {
       if(A.empty() || A.size()<2) return;
       int low = 0; 
       int high = A.size()-1;
       for(int i = low; i<=high;) {
           if(A[i]==0) {
              // swap A[i] and A[low] and i,low both ++
              int temp = A[i];
              A[i] = A[low];
              A[low]=temp;
              i++;low++;
           }else if(A[i]==2) {
               //swap A[i] and A[high] and high--;
              int temp = A[i];
              A[i] = A[high];
              A[high]=temp;
              high--;
           }else {
               i++;
           }
       }
   }
```

My question is, why is `i` incremented when `A[i]==0` and `A[i]==1` and not when `A[i]==2`?  Using pen and paper, the algorithm *just works* to give me the answer; but could you please provide some intuition?

Thanks!

Comment: Walk through it on paper to find out why.

Comment: @tadman, yeah I did and it works.  But I don't get the intuition behind doing that. :(

Comment: It simply shifts all '0' (red) to the bottom of the array and all `2` (blue) to the top, the `1` (white) is left in the middle by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This steps through the array and maintains the constraint that the elements `0..i` are sorted, and all either `0` or `1`. (The `2`'s that were there get swapped to the end of the array.)

When `A[i]==0`, you're swapping the element at `i` (which we just said was `0`) with the element at `low`, which is the first `1`-element (if any) in the range `0..i`. Hence, after the swap, `A[i]==1` which is OK (the constraint is still valid). We can safely move forward in the array now. The same is true if `A[i]==1` originally, in which case no swap is performed.

When `A[i]==2`, you're essentially moving element `i` (which we just said was `2`) to the end of the array. But you're also moving something from the end of the array into element `i`'s place, and we don't know what that element is (because we haven't processed it before, unlike the `A[i]==0` case). Hence, we cannot safely move `i` forward, because the new element at `A[i]` might not be in the right place yet. We need another iteration to process the new `A[i]`.

Comment: Nice explanation.  Thank you! :)

Comment: One qq - you say, _we are swapping the element `0` with the element at `low`, which is the first `1`-element (if any) in the range `0..i`_.  However, will that not give us the ranges as `[1, 1, ..., 0, 0, ...]` instead of what we want?

Comment: No, the elements `0..(low-1)` are all `0`'s, and the elements `low..(i-1)` are all `1`'s. Upon seeing a `0`, you swap it with the leftmost `1` (at index `low`), and increase `low`. So the section of `0`'s has grown by one element (the newly-swapped one).

Comment: Okay, got it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

That is, because for 0s and 1s, only items left of the current item are handled and those have already been reviewed / sorted. Only for 2s items from the right end of the array are handled, which haven't been looked at yet.

To be more specific: In this specific example only three different states are handled:

1. the current item being reviewed equals 0: in this case this sorting algorithm just puts this item at the end of all zeros, which have already been sorted (aka A[low]). Also the item which was at A[low] before can only be a 0 or 1 (since they have already sorted) which means you can just swap with the current item and not break the sequence. Now the interesting part: up until now, every item from A[0] over A[low] to A[i] has been already sorted, so the next item which has to be reviewed will be A[i + 1], hence the i++
2. the current item equals 1: in this case, no swapping has to be done, since all 0s and 1s has already been put in A[0] to A[i - 1] and all 2s have already been put at the end of the array. That means, the next item to be reviewed is A[i + 1], hence the i++
3. the current item equals 2: in this case, the current item will be put at the end of the array, next to (i.e., to the left of) all the other already sorted 2s (A[high]). The item, which will be swapped from A[high] to A[i] has not been sorted yet and therefor has to be reviewed in the next step, hence th i = i;

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  One qq - _the current item will be put at the end of the array to all the other already sorted 2s (A[high])_ - wouldn't it in fact be put at the left of all the `2`s?

Comment: yes! absolutely correct. it will be put one position left of all the 2s at the end. The item currently residing there is therefor of unknown value (could be 0, 1 or 2), that is why it still has to be processed

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!